# How to design Watchdog timer that reset the system if Watchdog counter is not cleared at least every 1/4 seconds

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded, msp430

This is the code I have for a green LED blinking every 2s with watchdog mode for MSP432.

```
#include "msp.h"

void main(void)
 {
     volatile uint32_t i;
     WDT_A->CTL = WDT_A_CTL_PW & 0xFF00;
     WDT_A->CTL = WDT_A_CTL_PW | WDT_A_CTL_IS_5;
     P2DIR |= BIT1;
     while (1) // continuous loop
     {
         P2OUT ^=BIT1; // Blink P1.0 LED
         for (i =6000000; i> 0; i--); // Delay with 3Mhz clock.
     }
 }
```

How to design Watchdog timer that reset the system if Watchdog counter is not cleared at least every 1/4 seconds?

Comment: Make an outer loop around your delay loop. Shorten the delay time. Trigger the watchdog inside the outer loop.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So Something like this,
         for(j= 30000; j> 0; j--)
              {
                   WDT_A->CTL = WDT_A_CTL_PW & 0XFF00;
                   for(I=3000000; I>0; I-- );
              }
I apologize I am very good at programming.

Comment: if 6000000 means 2s, and your watchdog needs to be triggered each 1/4s, you have to divide number this by eight, and your outer loop has to count to eight to make it the same delay.

Comment: @Janka Ok, so you answered his question, how will he mark it as accepted?

Comment: @pipe Janka had to post an answer, which you could accept

Comment: @Mike But he did not. He chose to ignore the information when posting his comment, which states _"avoid answering questions in comments."_ The question will now remain listed as unsolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purist/best practice solution is that your program should only kick the watchdog once, at the top of the eternal loop in main(). Thus the best practice is this:

```
void main (void)
{
  ...

  uint32_t count = 0;

  for(;;)
  {
    kick_dog();

    if(count < max)
    {
      blink_led();
      delay(n);
      count++;
    }
  } // for(;;)
}
```

But of course busy-delay loops is an amateur solution in itself. Professional code would instead utilize on-chip hardware timers. Such as:

```
void main (void)
{
  ...
  init_timer();
  ...

  uint32_t count = 0;
  timer_busy = false;

  for(;;)
  {
    kick_dog();
    led();
  }
}

static void led (void)
{
  if(!timer_busy)
  {
    blink_led();
    timer_busy = true;          
    start_timer(); // some hw timer that will clear the timer_busy flag from its ISR

    count++;
    if(count == max)
    {
      // do something
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not really familiar with MSP controller, but the answer should be something like this:

```
#include "msp.h"

void main(void)
{
    volatile uint32_t i, j;
    WDT_A->CTL = WDT_A_CTL_PW & 0xFF00;
    WDT_A->CTL = WDT_A_CTL_PW | WDT_A_CTL_IS_5;
    P2DIR |= BIT1;
    while (1) // continuous loop
    {
        P2OUT ^=BIT1; // Blink P1.0 LED
        for (j = 8; j > 0; j--)
        {
             WDT_A->CTL = WDT_A_CTL_PW & 0XFF00;
             for (i = 750000; i > 0; i--);      // Delay with 3Mhz clock, 0,26s.
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup and Reset your Watchdog Timer in one go. If you setup and reset separately then it keeps on resetting.

```
#include "msp.h"
void main(void)
{
WDT_A->CTL = WDT_A_CTL_PW | WDT_A_CTL_HOLD;     // stop watchdog timer

//RGB Leds
P2->DIR = BIT2 | BIT1 | BIT0;
P2->OUT &= ~(BIT2 | BIT1 | BIT0);

//Startup Sequence
P2->OUT = BLUE_LED;
delay_ms(1000);
P2->OUT = GREEN_LED;
delay_ms(1000);
P2->OUT &= ~(BLUE_LED | GREEN_LED);

while(1){

    //Resetting and setting-up simultaneously 
    WDT_A->CTL = WDT_A_CTL_PW|              // Password
                 WDT_A_CTL_CNTCL|           // Clear the timer counter
                 WDT_A_CTL_SSEL__ACLK |     // clock- source = 32.728kHz
                 WDT_A_CTL_IS_4;            // 1-SEC Interval

    P2->OUT ^= RED;
    delay_ms(500);// you can test different times here to check your watchdog working
}
```

}